# Why no alert box appears?

Tags: javascript

```
   <select id="monthSelect" name="month">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
   </select>
<script type="text/javascrip">
  var selectedMonth = month.options[index].value;
  alert(selectedMonth);
</script>
```

Why no alert appears? I am trying to understand the basic concept of JS.

Comment: "index" is undefined

Comment: you have mistyped "text/javascrip", it should be "text/javascript" (t at the end)

Comment: you should also define `index` and `month` variables.

Comment: The better question would be: Why would you expect one to?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a "t" on the end of your script type.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascrip">
```

Comment: and better to drop type attribute all together.

Comment: @Balder: It may well be **part** of the problem. :-)

Comment: All browser will interprete it correctly, the problem is a missing month variable, which makes js crash

Comment: @Balder No they won't. Try it. The reason the alert doesn't show up is because the type attribute is invalid.

Comment: Actually I tested, you're right it won't work with the wrong attr
https://jsfiddle.net/jno7wrh7/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are incorrect. Currently, your `month` and `index` variables will be undefined.

1. use `text/javascript` (or just skip it)
2. get the element by its ID
3. get the selected element using `selectedIndex`

Here's a working sample:

```
<select id="monthSelect" name="month">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect')
    var i = e.selectedIndex;
    var selectedMonth = e.options[i].value;
    alert(selectedMonth);
</script>
```

alternatively, you can call the alert when the change event of the  fires:

```
<select id="monthSelect" name="month" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

or you can even pass the value to a custom function of your own:

```
<select id="monthSelect" name="month" onchange="MyFunction(this.value)">
<script>
    function MyFunction(val) {
        alert(val);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but this version gives inmediately an alert with "1".

Comment: Correct, that's what the script does: it immediately retrieves the selected value and calls the alert. You can make it into a function and call that function when the `select` change event fires

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e=document.getElementById("monthSelect");
var selectedMonth =e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedMonth);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have to call a function on change event of your drop down. Use following code it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetIndex() {
        var ddlValue = document.getElementById('monthSelect');

        var index = ddlValue.value;

        alert(index);
    }
</script>

<select id="monthSelect" name="month" onchange="GetIndex()">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
</select>
```